# How to increment textbox when a button is pressed in another page

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, increment

So this is really bugging me - I am trying to make it that everytime a item is chosen in one page a textbox in another page should be incremented.

**If items are greater than 0 txtbox should increment textbox**

```
 if ((Menu.VanillaQ > 0)  || (Menu.LCQ > 0) || (Menu.ChocQ > 0) ) 
                {
                    Orders++;
                    NoOfOrder.Text = Orders.ToString();

                }
            }
```

**Menu Class declaring variables**

```
    public static double VanillaQ;        
    public static double LCQ;   
    public static double ChocQ;

//Code for one Item 

        if (VanillaQ <= 100)
        {

            VanillaQ = VanillaQ+1;
            txtAmount.Text = VanillaQ.ToString(); //Gets quantity of each item and sets it as a string 
        }
```

**Make new order btn-sets all variables to 0**

```
  private void Orderbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.BanQ = 0;
        Menu.VanillaQ = 0;
        Menu.StrawQ = 0;
        Menu.MintQ = 0;
        Menu.ChocQ = 0;
        Menu.CurryQ = 0;
        Menu.EggQ = 0;
        Menu.LagerQ = 0;
        Menu.LCQ = 0;


         Frame.Navigate(typeof(Type));
    }
```

Right now it only increments one time no matter how many loops I take. And after I press the Make new order button the variables are all resetted to 0 therefore after if item is chosen variable will be greater than 0 and textbox should be incremented. But it only increments once which really confuses mr :s

Comment: I didn't see any loops in your code other than some if clause

Comment: when is the first code snippet executed?